# polymer iron-form submit issue with paper-input validation

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, polymer-1.0

I am using iron-form in polymer and submitting my form using
`Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit()`
In this form i am using several `<paper-input>` elements with auto validation like this 
`<paper-input name = "heightcms" label="Height (CM)" auto-validate pattern="^\d+(\.\d+)?$" error-message="numbers only"></paper-input>`

**Requirement** : To allow only numbers and decimal in the input box
**Issue**: I have tried several regex patters from simple to complex but with every pattern , i get the 400 error - Bad Request. The submit works when either the input is empty or doesn't contain any decimal.

Although , when i start input in the field , the red hover goes the moment the pattern is matched , but the form submit always throws error.

The regex pattern which i have tried are

- [0-9.]
- ^\d+(.\d+)?$
- [0-9.]*

I have also searched SO questions about this a lot but not able to solve this issue. Can some one please guide me in right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^\d+\.?\d*$
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7yU5/1)

---

Explaining:

```
^       # from start
\d+     # match at least '+' one digit '\d'
\.?     # the dot is optional    -- tip: remember that you need to escape the dot
\d*     # 'if' there are more digits
$       # must end after that
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry but still the same issue. I guess it has more to do with the iron-form behaviour in Polymer where it is not understanding if the validation has passed ..

Answer (score 0):

if it helps , the older version of iron-form has some issues while sending the form data with validation. The suggested resolution is to mention the content/type as 'Application/Json'  and ( the one which solved my issue) to update the iron-form to latest version (1.0.8). Most importantly , clear the browser cache before testing your changes.

Thanks to washington guedes for ruling out the problem with regex in my case.

Regards
Varun